# User photos album in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, paperclip, photo-gallery, image-upload

I am building an app where user can upload pictures. For now only one picture at a time will do. I have searched around the Web and here at Stack Overflow, but don't really seem to find what I am looking for or at least I don't know what I am looking for if it exists here at the site.

I have tried implementing paperclip and allow users to upload pictures through that and not deleting the old picture when uploading a new one. But I don't really know where to go from here to display all the pictures that a user has uploaded. How do I do this the best way? Should I continue using paperclip or is there an even more suitable gem for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), over Paperclip, because it has more options and easy to setup. However without knowing what is your ultimate goal for your photo app, it's a little hard to tell what to do next.

If you have a roadmap or feature list, that would be helpful for us to help you with your next move.

But, if it is a simple photo app, might as well try to build it on top of an existing CMS like [Refinery](http://refinerycms.com/); you could easily build a plugin to upload images with Refinery.

Comment: It is not just a photo app. It is an app with user profiles and each user should have an album where photos that they upload is stored. Photos should be able to be uploaded from an iphone app and directly from the Web application.

Comment: hi @r08o, in that case I advice you to build from scratch, coz it has more control. and following are the tools you might can get help with "devise (for authentication), carrierwave (for image upload), twitterbootstrap (for layouts)", all the best :)

Comment: I have already got bootstrap and devise with omniauth running. And working image upload with paperclip. But it only allows be to have one photo per user. I will look into carrierwave and hopefully get it to work.

Comment: yes it should be, since you have already implemented paperclip, check this out to migrate https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#migrating-from-paperclip

Comment: Thanks. I think I will keep the paperclip just for avatars though, since I have that up and running nicely already.

Comment: How would you suggest that I make something like a "photo album" for each user?

Comment: @r08o, have a many to many table for users to albums, like albums_users with album_id and user_id coz the reason is later then you can expand this to One user can have many albums as well as one album can have many owners, but simplest way is one-to-many (one user can have many albums) but not a very expandable architecture. :)